# How to convert a date format (YYYY-MM-DD) to (YYYY,MM,DD) in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

How to convert a date format `(YYYY-MM-DD)` to `(YYYY,MM,DD)` in Python

OR, I have a `date = 2020-06-11` which I want to convert into seconds.

Works:  `d2 = (dt.datetime(2020,6,30) - t0).total_seconds()`

Fails: `d2 = (dt.datetime(2020-6-30) - t0).total_seconds()`

How do I do it ?

Comment: try `dt.datetime.strptime('2020-6-30', '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: In Python, `2020-6-30` is the same as 2020 minus 6 minus 30, which is not what you want. Whereas `2020,6,30` is valid Python, you separate arguments with commas in Python. What you want is the convert the string `"2020-6-30"` to a `datetime` object.

Comment: see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) how to construct datetime objects

Comment: Please clarify which aspect(s) of this particular situation are not covered by the many existing resources available.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to cast a string to a datetime object, you can use strptime for this.

```
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.strptime('2020-06-11', '%Y,%m,%d')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior